# trying to run parallel programming using parfor

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I'm trying to run parallel programming on insertion sort using Matlab `parfor`, but its giving an error

```
clear A
t=cputime;
x = 1 : 1000;
n = length(x);
parfor j = 2:n
    pivot = x(j);
    i = j;
    while ((i > 1) && (x(i - 1) > pivot))
        x(i) = x(i - 1);
        i = i - 1;
    end
    x(i) = pivot;
end
cputime-t
```

Error: The variable x in a parfor cannot be classified.
See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Overview".

Comment: The problem is you will be changing the same `x(i)` for different `j`'s, which is a problem for parallel processing, as you never know which `j` will run next.

Comment: `parfor` is designed only for order-independent parallel for-loops. I don't *think* it can be used to implement a parallel sort. You need something like `spmd` to do that. In fact, `sort` is implemented for distributed arrays, and operates in parallel.